# merged charts are appearing one over another. I want them side by side

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want two charts: pie chart and area percentage chart in same svg. Pie chart will be in left 50% and area chart will be in right 50%.

But in following code: pie chart appears over area chart. what am i doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Highcharts - Combined Chart</title>
    <!-- Include Highcharts library -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <!-- Include Highcharts exporting module -->
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Container for the combined chart -->
    <div id="combinedChartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: flex;">
        <div id="pieChartContainer" style="flex: 1; padding: 10px;"></div>
        <div id="areaChartContainer" style="flex: 1; padding: 10px;"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Pie Chart Data
        var pieData = [{
            name: 'Category 1',
            y: 45
        }, {
            name: 'Category 2',
            y: 55
        }];

        // Area Percentage Chart Data
        var areaPercentageData = [{
            name: 'Category 1',
            data: [20, 30, 40],
            stack: 'percentage'
        }, {
            name: 'Category 2',
            data: [30, 40, 50],
            stack: 'percentage'
        }];

        // Create the combined chart
        var combinedChart = Highcharts.chart('combinedChartContainer', {
            chart: {
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Combined Chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['1-Jan', '2-Jan', '3-Jan']
            },
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage'
                },
                max: 100,
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{total}%'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    stacking: 'percentage',
                    lineColor: '#ffffff',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        lineColor: '#ffffff'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'Category 1',
                data: areaPercentageData[0].data,
                stack: 'percentage',
                renderTo: 'areaChartContainer' // specify the area chart container div
            }, {
                type: 'area',
                name: 'Category 2',
                data: areaPercentageData[1].data,
                stack: 'percentage',
                renderTo: 'areaChartContainer' // specify the area chart container div
            }, {
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Categories',
                data: pieData,
                size: 150,
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f}%'
                },
                renderTo: 'pieChartContainer' // specify the pie chart container div
            }],
            exporting: {
                enabled: true  // Enable exporting
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of problem:
[image]

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the documentation or the source code the option
`renderTo` for a series, nor anywhere else than the `renderTo` element provided
for the chart itself when constructed. Furthermore, if you use "Inspect/Elements"
tool of your browser you'll see that the inner divs are deleted, since the
chart takes control of the outer div you provided for `Highcharts.chart` and
overwrites its contents for its own purposes.

Comment: ... I haven't yet seen in highcharts this
approach with one chart object, parts of which are rendering in different divs; 
can you provide a reference or an example of it working? The typical approach is
to have *two charts constructed* for the two divs, sharing data and synchronizing behavior through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior and now you need to position series. Here is the example config:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    marginLeft: 0
  },
  yAxis: [{
    left: '50%',
    width: '50%'
  }],

  xAxis: [{
    left: '50%',
    width: '50%'
  }],

  series: [{
    type: 'areaspline',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }, {
    type: 'pie',
    center: ['20%', '50%'],
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }]
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kdr6cz08/